After the first 'move to' block is executed, the subsequent ones do not work
enter image description here
I made my process like this.. And I don't know the reason why only the first 'move to' block is executed, and why doesn't it proceed after that....
How can I fix this problem??
I want to collect 5 agents, combine them into one box(batch), and then move the box using one transporter.
enter image description here
enter image description here

looks like your conveyors cannot "convey", check how you set up the actual network (or share your properties of that block)

"convey" block's property is default... I really want to fix this problem..

this may be the problem... Share a screenshot, make our lives easy, not yours :)

I have added a screenshot at the end of the question. If you need any additional information, please let me know. Thank you so much! Your help has been incredibly valuable for my research..

now start "sherlocking": I cant see the 11 frames on any conveyor, which is conveyor6? Are they on it? What if you only add 2 frames, not 12? Start getting to the root of the problem, all looks well from afar :)

As Benjamin said, it would be great if you could formulate your question with a little more detail and set up the whole thing as a simple example project. So just one conveyor, the MoveTo and the batch block. In that case we could solve the problem very quickly.
The problem you have is that your first object remains on the conveyor because you have not selected in the properties that the object should leave the conveyor and you do not say so at a later point in time. For this reason, you can also see on your screenshot that the last object does not travel to the end of the conveyor.
To fix your Problem just mark the leaveConveyorOnExit Propertie in the Convey Block. Below you can see a simple Example Model



Sorry for my lack of English skills and for not being able to ask my questions clearly. I will try the method you suggested. Thank you so much!

no Problem, if the answer works for you please remeber to mark the question as resolved else please ask for further Details
